# Comprehensive ajax page for Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Controller named ProductsController. In that controller are several actions such as socks and towels. I also have views of socks and towels. The view pages of socks and towels have the exact same form inside it. I'm going to use ajax in both files for the forms. Since the form is the exact same in both views, I see it pointless to create multiple ajax js files for the actions to call when ajax is called. How can I have both actions socks and towels call the same js.erb file instead of `socks.js.erb` and `towels.js.erb` respectively?

My controller and the action socks.

```
def socks
 @socks = Socks.all

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @socks }
   #ok, I get the line below is needed for ajax. Is there something I could add for
   #the action not to call socks.js.erb and instead a different file, say ajax.js.erb
   format.js
 end

end
```

Comment: What do you mean? Ajax calls land in controllers, not some javascript.

Comment: You are right. Then Rails automatically calls a JavaScript Embedded Ruby (.js.erb) file with the same name as the action. What I want to know is how can I have a js file that all controllers send to. Sorry if I'm confusing you. It's hard for me to describe exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `render` here. Using it you can render a template/view of another action. See the doc: [Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

```
render 'products/show'
render :template => 'products/show'
render "/u/apps/warehouse_app/current/app/views/products/show"
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I want. I rewrote my question to give a real-life example.

Comment: Why do you think so? It will do what you want.

Comment: The bigger question for me is HOW to get to work. I'll play with it and figure it out. This is my first time creating ajax in rails so bear with me.

Comment: `render` is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

as [Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125816/sergio-tulentsev) rightly said, you can do exactly that using the **render** command. Basically, in both socks and towels actions, you can render a common ajax.js.erb file when the respond_to is for JS.

I am adding this answer however because of your comment. It seems that your socks and towels methods as well as the forms and associated responses are very similar. If that is the case, why not use a single action for the same? Basically, you can use a URL parameter to specify the nature of product in the ProductsController actions.

So you would have something like:

```
def ProductsController

   def index
       if params[:nature] == "socks"
          @socks = Sock.all
          respond_to do |format|
             format.html # index.html.erb
             format.json { render json: @socks }
             format.js
          end
       elsif params[:nature] == "towels"
          @towels = Towel.all
          respond_to do |format|
             format.html # index.html.erb
             format.json { render json: @towels }
             format.js
          end
       end
   end
end
```

Now you would need 2 view files index.html.erb and index.js.erb and there you can check the params value again and display the relevant collection.

This is not an ideal solution, but more a quick fix.

Failing that, you can also define a new action method in the ProductsController and have both forms point to that.